# How to create a postponed action programmatically?

Tags: 7, rules

There's a task.

When user is registered he's assigned an advanced role, but in three month this role should be taken away.

Could you clarify me, is it possible to create this action **programmatically** using opportunities of modules rules and rules_scheduler ?

Or, is it possible to assign programmatically a postponed executing for some php function via modules rules and rules scheduler ?

I found a function rules_scheduler_schedule_task in the rules_scheduler.module file, but i can't understand how to create parameter $task.

Could you help me, how to do it ?

Comment: Yes, you guessed. I don't have extensive experience in working with Rules UI. And moreover, being a programmer, I'm interested to solve this task programmatically, via module with hooks.

Comment: There is a second raison to create it programmatically. If i create a module, then I should describe and do it programmatically. Module is installed and rules are enable. And vice versa.

Comment: [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) does this (allows roles to be added with an expiration date) and provides some rules triggers; it might be useful to look at that code.

Comment: I thought rules scheduler can do what you're describing.. Why are you asking about doing it programmatically? If you say programmatically, it means to use php code, in Drupal anyway.